# Anville Town's Lost Luggage Gifts

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

What items does the Anville lost luggage guy actually give you? I've gotten rare candies, proteins, and hp ups. Does anyone have a definitive list? Also, what determines the number of items that are received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are, this is the official list out of the Pokémon Black and White guide book:

- Calcium
- Carbos
- Iron
- Protein
- Zinc
- Elixir
- Rare Candy
- HP Up
- Max Revive

Comment: Very cool, does the guide say what determines which item you get and how many?

Comment: unfortunately not. I believe it is just random